# print date from string as date in bash

Tags: bash

What is the bashonic way of converting the following text:

```
Specifications of bla/bla.txt created at 181438 on the 20160720
```

into:

```
Specifications of bla/bla.txt created at 18:14:38 on the 20th July 2016
```

I'm currently generating my message with:

```
printf "Specifications of %s created at %d on %d\n" "$1" "$thehour" "$thedate"
```

And `$thehour` and `$thedate` are extracted from `bla.txt`. They are not related to any file tags or to the actual creation date of the file.

I'm basically asking if BASH already offers such functionality, and if not, how can one achieve that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `date`:

```
$ thehour=181438
$ thedate=20160720
$ printf 'Specifications of bla/bla.txt created at %s on %s\n' "$(sed \
   's/../&:/g' <<<"$thehour"|sed 's/.$//')" "$(date -d "$thedate" '+%dth %B %Y')"
```

**Output:**

```
Specifications of bla/bla.txt created at 18:14:38 on 20th July 2016
```

---

- `sed 's/../&:/g' <<<"$thehour"|sed 's/.$//'` gets the `thehour` variable expansion in desired format
- `date -d "$thedate" '+%dth %B %Y'` gets the `thedate` variable expansion i.e. the date is desired format using `date`

Comment: Alternatively could use a single call to sed: `sed -E 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1:\2:\3/'` (or even just use `(..)` for each capture group).

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks. Thought about that, but spawning two processes seems reasonable in this case given the readability, also i'm not sure about the potential performance gain of your one given the steps involved.